# iOS Encryption using RSA public key file in DER format

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, public-key-encryption

I am trying to use an RSA public key to encrypt data within an iOS app to send to a customer's service over the web. The key was generated using openssl:

```
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048
openssl rsa -in private.pem -pubout -out public.der -outform der
```

I then try to use the key as follows:

```
NSString *aPublicKeyPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"public" ofType:@"der"];
NSFileManager* aFileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSData* myCertData = [aFileMgr contentsAtPath: aPublicKeyPath];
CFDataRef myCertDataRef = (__bridge CFDataRef)myCertData;
SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData (kCFAllocatorDefault, myCertDataRef);
```

The contents of the cert load correctly into myCertData, but SecCertificateCreateWithData returns nil without throwing an exception. There is no result code to check, so I don't know why it isn't working.

FYI - The key appears valid. If I check the key, I get this output:

```
$ openssl rsa -text -in public.der -inform DER -pubin
Modulus (2048 bit):
00:a7:21:90:62:96:15:38:f8:43:5b:33:9f:00:a0:
12:51:63:0e:5c:72:58:05:6a:99:93:d8:6e:f4:d8:
4a:91:cb:dc:74:de:3c:38:63:06:41:5f:63:1e:e9:
70:81:90:e9:f0:e4:78:0a:00:5c:d3:ee:6a:5a:c1:
d7:9a:62:af:f3:45:91:5a:86:bc:aa:8f:86:f5:4f:
3d:01:4b:64:11:31:6f:c1:ab:07:e5:b8:5b:46:8e:
b5:c0:a1:2c:7b:65:1b:09:a9:12:b4:99:f8:77:46:
fa:62:52:04:32:98:09:1c:69:89:52:8c:30:77:af:
51:f2:30:0d:99:33:d3:2b:39:6c:6b:0e:19:ad:67:
10:69:0f:4e:3c:7a:a4:41:bd:87:4e:1d:65:b7:62:
7e:0d:b5:f7:ab:3d:b8:40:f1:c9:8c:c3:1e:9e:7c:
02:67:3a:21:ca:3a:3c:cd:d8:98:fe:4c:ab:30:d4:
f8:2d:3e:78:c3:f0:39:54:15:8a:b7:16:77:ca:3b:
ab:42:5e:70:3e:48:fd:a3:6c:55:5e:66:4b:33:d6:
c0:9c:db:2d:d2:26:78:b8:ca:69:6c:77:6d:38:ab:
77:a0:68:ad:e5:2d:11:50:57:b6:16:dc:b3:e2:82:
bb:07:88:08:a4:87:4c:c6:37:9e:33:ea:5a:f9:b4:
0c:6f
Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
writing RSA key
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEApyGQYpYVOPhDWzOfAKAS
UWMOXHJYBWqZk9hu9NhKkcvcdN48OGMGQV9jHulwgZDp8OR4CgBc0+5qWsHXmmKv
80WRWoa8qo+G9U89AUtkETFvwasH5bhbRo61wKEse2UbCakStJn4d0b6YlIEMpgJ
HGmJUowwd69R8jANmTPTKzlsaw4ZrWcQaQ9OPHqkQb2HTh1lt2J+DbX3qz24QPHJ
jMMennwCZzohyjo8zdiY/kyrMNT4LT54w/A5VBWKtxZ3yjurQl5wPkj9o2xVXmZL
M9bAnNst0iZ4uMppbHdtOKt3oGit5S0RUFe2Ftyz4oK7B4gIpIdMxjeeM+pa+bQM
bwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

iOS does not appear to support directly reading a public key as generated above without some serious hacking, see [this blog post where public header is manually stripped from key to get it to load](http://blog.flirble.org/2011/01/05/rsa-public-key-openssl-ios/). I was able to make this work, but I feel it is not a good approach for me to put into my app.

Finally got a solution I am happy with. As stated in the documentation, the certificate must be in DER format, so I regenerated it using this command and it worked:

```
$ openssl req -x509 -out public_key.crt -outform DER -new -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout private_key.pem
```

Then I use the key as follows:

```
NSString *aPublicKeyPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"public" ofType:@"der"];
NSFileManager* aFileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSData* aCertData = [aFileMgr contentsAtPath: aPublicKeyPath];
SecCertificateRef aCertRef = SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFDataRef)aCertData);

if (aCertRef != NULL) {
    SecKeyRef aPublicKeyRef = NULL;
    SecTrustRef aTrustRef = NULL;
    SecPolicyRef aPolicyRef = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();

    if (aPolicyRef) {
        if (SecTrustCreateWithCertificates((CFTypeRef)aCertRef, aPolicyRef, &aTrustRef) == noErr) {
            SecTrustResultType result;
            if (SecTrustEvaluate(aTrustRef, &result) == noErr) {
                aPublicKeyRef = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(aTrustRef);
            }
        }
    }

    if (aPolicyRef) CFRelease(aPolicyRef);
    if (aTrustRef) CFRelease(aTrustRef);
    if (aCertRef) CFRelease(aCertRef);
    NSString* aClearTextString = @"This is the test string";
    NSString* aEncryptedString = [[self class] encryptRSA:aClearTextString
                                                      key:aPublicKeyRef];
}
```

The encryption routine is:

```
+(NSString *)encryptRSA:(NSString *)plainTextString key:(SecKeyRef)publicKey         
{
    size_t cipherBufferSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey);
    uint8_t *cipherBuffer = malloc(cipherBufferSize);
    uint8_t *nonce = (uint8_t *)[plainTextString UTF8String];
    SecKeyEncrypt(publicKey,
              kSecPaddingOAEP,
              nonce,
              strlen( (char*)nonce ),
              &cipherBuffer[0],
              &cipherBufferSize);
    NSData *encryptedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cipherBuffer length:cipherBufferSize];
    return [encryptedData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/#//apple_ref/c/func/SecCertificateCreateWithData

You are trying to load public key. This API expects public key certificate, not public key.

It says

> Returns NULL if the data passed in the data parameter is not a valid
>   DER-encoded **X.509 certificate**.

So, make public key of it or use other API to load public key.

Comment: What api can I use? I've been looking all day.

Comment: I am not able to find any suitable API. You can build certificate out of your public key using OpenSSL.

Comment: Ok, generated the key certificate in DER format. Once I did that, I was able to load the cert. Thanks for the suggestion.